# What is the significance that Caleb outlived Joshua?

Tags: joshua

Joshua 24:29
New International Version

> After these things, Joshua son of Nun, the servant of the LORD, died at the age of a hundred and ten.

> Judges 1:1 After the **death** of Joshua, the Israelites asked the Lord, “Who of us is to go up first to fight against the Canaanites?” ...
> 12And **Caleb** said, “I will give my daughter Aksah in marriage to the man who attacks and captures Kiriath Sepher.” 13Othniel son of Kenaz, Caleb’s younger brother, took it; so Caleb gave his daughter Aksah to him in marriage.

Apparently, Caleb outlived Joshua. He was the last Hebrew who was born in Egypt. He went from being a slave in Egypt to being a big landowner in Canaan. Is there a significance in this?

Comment: Just because you find someone mentioned later in the chapter does not necessarily mean it is next in line in the narrative(e.g. Caleb's inheritance is mentioned in Joshua).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the reasons I think that enabled Caleb to outlive Joshua based on the below verses. I have highlighted the sections that may help ...

1. From the below verse we know that he was favoured in God's sight.

> **Numbers 14:24** ~ But because my servant Caleb has a different spirit and follows me wholeheartedly, I will bring him into the land he went to, and his descendants will inherit it.

2. From the below verses we know that he was full of vigor and in good health
3. We also know that he trusted God and knew he would be able to kill the worst of the Canaanites (both Giants & Hill country)

> **Joshua 14:10** “Now then, just as the Lord promised, he has kept me alive for forty-five years since the time he said this to Moses, while Israel moved about in the wilderness. ***So here I am today, eighty-five years old! 11 I am still as strong today as the day Moses sent me out; I’m just as vigorous to go out to battle now as I was then.*** 12 Now give me this hill country that the Lord promised me that day. You yourself heard then that the Anakites were there and their cities were large and fortified, but, the Lord helping me, I will drive them out just as he said.”

4. Last but not least of all Executive leadership of Joshua would have caused him to have stress and anxiety and wear out faster than Caleb. Remember these are the same Israelites (generation 2) that caused Moses to fall on his face a zillion times (ok I exaggerated it) and not be able to enter the promised land.

God Bless

Answer (score 0):

If Caleb was still alive when Joshua died, wouldn't you expect that leadership of the tribe would go to him instead of to Judges?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/49651)